# Angular 7 select method don't work on dynamically created ngb-tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular 7 with ng-bootstrap. I am calling API to get data from database. At page load I dynamically create tabs. That all works, but when I want to select default tab on load It does't work.

I tried .select method, id and attr.id setting, tried to set active.Id on ngb-tabset,... Nothing works. Someone know where the problem is?

Code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-tabs-3cavxt

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the [mcve] code to the post. See [ask]

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the tab once people is loaded completely.

Modify `ngOnInit()` like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.get().subscribe(people => {
      this.people = people;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.tabSet.select('Samantha')
      }, 0);
    },
      error => console.log(error));
  }
```

See [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-tabs-qk34yd?file=app%2Ftabset-config.ts)